# How to calculate the percentage of failed requests (HTTP status 401) using Splunk query?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following query

```
<base query>  | rex field=msg "HTTP/1.1\\\" (?<http_status>\d{3})" 
| where http_status=200 OR http_status=401 
| eval event_date=strftime(_time, "%x") 
| chart count over event_date by http_status
```

that gives me the following table

```
event_date      200     401
==========      ===     ===
11/28/21        61      24
11/29/21        295     96
```

However, I need an additional column that shows the percentage of status 401 compared to the total, i.e., "401"/("200"+"401"), as the following:

```
event_date      200     401     401 percentage
==========      ===     ===     ==============
11/28/21        61      24      28.24%
11/29/21        295     96      24.55%
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `eval` to compute the percentage.

```
| eval "401 percentage" = round('401'*100/('200'+'401'),2)."%"
```

The `round` function limits the calculation to 2 decimal places and `."%"` adds a percent symbol to the end.  BTW, be sure to use single quotes where I have so Splunk knows it's a field name rather than a string literal.

Comment: Hi @RichG, I see a new "401 percentage" column after I appended your eval statement to the end of my query. It works,  thank you. However, when I go to Visualization, I don't see "401 percentage" on the line chart, but I see the "401 percentage" legend. Any idea why and how to get "401 percentage" to show up on the chart? Thank you.

Comment: I found out I need to remove the "%" at the end of the value to keep it as numeric for it to show up on the chart.